# how do i change the size of thing javascript thing (the java script starts from <!--Custom js file---> )

Tags: javascript, html

i wanna change the size of the javascript text , dk how to can anyone help?
this is the code im using just want to change the size of the java script
im new to html :P
this is the website link if anyone wanna see somethn about the javascript or smthn [Click Here](https://fenx.ga/partner.html)
(writing this cause it says it needs more details :P)

````
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fenx</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-white font-sans leading-normal tracking-normal">
<!--Header starts with here-->
 <header class = "header">
     <nav>
        <img src = "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/922099208914358312/922179674816258088/20211218_204000.png" class = "logo">
        <ul>
            <li> <a
            href="https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=786952203209277441&permissions=156732222710&scope=bot">Invite</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://discord.com/invite/YYbBasjkQN">Discord</a></li>
        </ul>
         <div> <center> <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/902875693946388482/923254050231812146/Webp.net-resizeimage_1.png" class="img" width="1145" height="114"> </div>
      
      
       
     </nav>

     <div class = "text-box">
       <div>
       <center> 

        <h1>
           <span class="auto-input" class="h3"></span>
        </h1>
      
       <p>
         These are Fenxs Partnered Discord Servers , To apply for Partnership Open a Ticket in Support Server or Tell us about your Server in Website Support Chat!
        </p>
      
        <!-- Custom js file-->
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>
<script>
    var typed = new Typed(".auto-input", {
        strings: ["Top Partners!", "Minecraft LFG",],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        backSpeed: 100,
        loop: true
    })
</script>
</div>
<!--end of js file-->
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu"> </p>
<img src = "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/922099208914358312/922179674816258088/20211218_204000.png" class = "img" width="87" height="84"> <font size="+10"> <p class = "uwu">         Minecraft LFG</p>

</body>
</html>
         ```
````

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body onload="typeWriter()">
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'The Quick Brown Fox Jump Over Your Mom HAAA GOT EMMMM  !!';
var speed = 100;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do i change the size of the text tho?